# Checkboxlist select Items from Datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying select Checkboxlist items from the Datatable values on page_load. But the following code doesn't seem to be working. Am I doing something wrong?

### .aspx page

```
  <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList2" runat="server"  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"  DataTextField="p_name" DataValueField="p_id" RepeatColumns="5" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
  </asp:CheckBoxList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="    select [p_id], [p_name] from [TABLE_A]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

### Code behind:

```
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        int l_id = this.Request.QueryString["l_id"].ToString();

        DataTable dt = controller.RetrieveData(l_id);
        List<string> selectedValues = CheckBoxList2.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                                .Select(li => li.Value)
                                .ToList();
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            if (selectedValues.Contains(dr["p_id"].ToString()))
                CheckBoxList2.Items.FindByValue(dr["p_id"].ToString()).Selected = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Page_Load event is called before binding the CheckBoxList items, that's why items are not selected.

Try to add a DataBound event in your checkBoxList to select the items you need.